# Defining attributes of a class using list comprehension gives AttributeError

Tags: python, oop, attributes, list-comprehension

I want to define a class which calculate the area of the circle and also count the number of circles

```
input 1,2,3

Output [3.14, 12.56, 28.26]

3
```

But I am not getting the desired output.

Code used:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        [self.radius for i in radius]  

    def area(self):
        return [3.14*self.radius**2 for i in self.radius]
        # return 3.14 * self.radius ** 2

inputradiusstr = "1,2,3"
list_radius = inputradiusstr.split(',')
obj2 = Circle(list_radius)
print(obj2.area())
```

Gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/file.py", line 11, in <module>
    obj2=Circle(list_radius)
  File "path/to/file.py", line 3, in __init__
    [self.radius for i in radius]
  File "path/to/file.py", line 3, in <listcomp>
    [self.radius for i in radius]
AttributeError: 'Circle' object has no attribute 'radius'
```

Comment: You need to document what you've tried, where it is failing, and what your output currently is.

Comment: I took a liberty of adding an output produced by your code and changing the title accordingly. If you don't agree with my edit, feel free to reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be misunderstanding when you'd use a class. Think of a class as a template for an object. When you call `Circle(...)`, you create an *instance* of that object, and it is perfectly acceptable to have multiple instances of one class.

In your example, consider making three circles for each of your three inputs (or however many inputs), then this simplifies your class because you don't need any lists.

```
class Circle:

    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def area(self):
        return 3.14 * self.radius**2
```

Then your main code would be dealing with each input as its own circle:

```
inputradiusstr="1,2,3"
list_radius=inputradiusstr.split(',')
for radius in list_radius:
    c = Circle(int(radius))
    print(c.area())
```

Note that we need to typecast the radius from a string to an integer so that we can perform calculations on it.

If you need to count the number of circles you create, then that's simply `len(list_radius)`.

Comment: I think it's worth to note that if a class has two methods, and one of them is `__init__` then [it shouldn't be a class](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0).

Answer (score 0):

```
inputradiusstr="1,2,3"
list_radius=[float(item) for item in inputradiusstr.split(',')]
```

So that, the radius can be float and not string.

```
  def area(self):
    return [3.14*self.radius**2 for i in self.radius]
    #return 3.14 * self.radius **2
```

Here in List comprehension, it should be `3.14*i**2`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should look like this:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def area(self):
        return [3.14 * r**2 for r in self.radius]
```

Answer (score 0):

Typecasting will work in your case.

```
inputradiusstr="1,2,3"
list_radius=list(map(int,inputradiusstr.split(',')))
obj2=Circle(list_radius)
print(obj2.area())
```

And your class has some indentation mismatch. I think its just while typing out the question.